# Calculate maximum Interface Speed 32 Bit 100 MHz

Tags: interface

I have a HSMC Interface which has 32 Bit width data word changing at 100 MHz. How is the correct maximum data throughput calculated?

Is it just dataword_length / clock_period [bits/ns]. And then I will convert to MByte/s. This is a question on the raw data speed (signalrate). There are no protocol headers involved here.

Comment: well. seriously, take a wild guess.

Comment: Specify which kind of HSMC are you using! Are you sure you have 32Bit. The standard connector provides 16bit lvds.

Comment: It is 32 Bit HSMC Connector at an FPGA. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clocked 32bits wide clocked at 100MHz would be:

100E6 DWords per second.

400E6 Bytes per second.

3200E6 Bits per second.